# errors with the intent and the confirmation in android

Tags: java, android-intent, if-statement, radio-button

i have an android activity that need to compare if the name and password are correct to let the user pass to the next activity using **intent**

but the problem is that whatever i put the system go the next activity  so can anyone help me ??
its a java error so i need help

## secondActivity.java

```
String username = "georges";
String pass = "password";

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSingIN) {

        if (rdg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdS) {

            SignIn(username, pass);
        } else if (rdg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdO) {

            Intent i_sign_o = new Intent(this,
                    SignOfficerActivity.class);
            startActivity(i_sign_o);
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRegister) {

    }
}

private void SignIn(String username2, String pass2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (username2 == username && pass2 == pass) {

        Intent i_sign_s = new Intent(this, SignSActivity.class);
        startActivity(i_sign_s);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
in the sighn in method is the error how to fix it ???
```

Comment: What error is it? Post the logcat please.

Comment: When you compare strings, you need to use `equals` or otherwise you compare references: `if (username2.equals(username) && pass2.equals(pass))`

Comment: i mean its is a Symantec error  in the if statement what ever i put in the username and password the system will allow the user to pass

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==` operator. Use `equals()`.

Comment: `username2` is always equal to `username` and `pass2` is always equal to `pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared those 2 variables:

```
String username = "georges";
String pass = "password";
```

And then you pass them to `SignIn`

```
SignIn(username, pass);
```

and compare parameters against the same variables. So obviously they are equal.

```
if (username2 == username && pass2 == pass)
```

You need to pass what the user entered to `SignIn`

---

BTW, when you compare strings, you need to use `equals()` or otherwise you compare references. The line should be (though it will always be true as well in the case above):

```
if (username2.equals(username) && pass2.equals(pass))
```

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: the problem is that what ever i put in the editbox  for the username and the password the system allow the user to pass even after i changed to .equal();

Comment: Because in the code above you pass the variables from the class and compare against themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare SignSActivity activity in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not comparing the string the user has entered with the `username` and `password`. Your code should look like this:

```
.....

String username;
String password;
String username1;
String password1;
EditText usertext;
EditText passtext;
.....

usertext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
passtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

username1 = usertext.getText().toString();
password1 = passtext.getText().toString();

.....
```

You can now pass the `username1` and `password1` to your `SignIn` method. i.e `SignIn(username1, password1)`

Then your `SignIn` method should compare like the strings like this:

```
private void SignIn(String username2, String pass2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (username2.equals(username) && pass2.equals(password)){

......

    }
}
```